# How to prepend runtime variable in a macro in C programming

Tags: c, macros

I have two macro defined like CPU1_BLA_BLA and CPU2_BLA_BLA .
These two macro are address for some registers. something like
#define CPU1_BLA_BLA 0x1234,

#define CPU2_BLA_BLA 0x4567

i have function which will rd/write some value from/to those registers. i am developing drivers so i want to have single API which will do the job instead of having two different API like below

i want to have single binary ( executable) for both cpu and detect which cpu it is running on run time

```
my_func_for_cpu()
{
   var=CPU1_BLA_BLA   //this is technically not correct to read,just showing example , but my intention is to read value from address 0x1234 here 
}
```

```
my_func_for_cpu()
{
   var=CPU2_BLA_BLA
}
```

Now i want to create single function for both cpu something like below

```
#if condition
   #define which_cpu CPU1 
#elif 
    #define which_cpu CPU2
```

```
my_func_for_cpu()
{
   var=(which_cpu)_BLA_BLA
}
```

which_cpu should be run time detect the CPU1 or CPU2

how can i implement this ??

i can find some condition which will detect weather it is running on CPU1 or CPU2
but not sure how to replace this variable at run time

Comment: [Edit] and show how exactly those macros are defined. That being said, your question is very unclear, [edit] and improve. Read this: [ask]

Comment: C makros are evaluated at compiletime. How do you run the code? Are you running two processes with the same executable? If so, try to use #if CPU1 … #else … #endif

Comment: @Fylyp with #if CPU1 kind of flag, i need to write same statement twice 
actually i need to develop it for multiple cpu and many registers write ,just name changed

Comment: Are you looking for `which_cpu ## _BLA_BLA`? Btw, instead of `#define CPU2_BLA_BLA =0x4567` you probably want `#define CPU2_BLA_BLA 0x4567`

Comment: XY problem? It looks like it to me

Comment: Shouldn't it be `#define CPU2_BLA_BLA 0x4567` instead of `#define CPU2_BLA_BLA =0x4567`? Please [edit] and write your code snippets properly. But anyway it's still unclear what you're trying to achieve.... Sounds like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me

Comment: Re "and detect which cpu it is running on run time" -- you cannot achieve this with macros.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Using macros/preprocessor and determining things at run-time are mutually exclusive. What I think you are actually looking for is look-up tables.

Given some

```
#define CPU1_BLA_BLA 0x1234
#define CPU2_BLA_BLA 0x4567
```

Then you can create a read-only look-up table (flash allocted on MCU systems):

```
static const uint16_t CPU [] =
{
  CPU1_BLA_BLA,
  CPU2_BLA_BLA,
};
```

And then your code becomes

```
var = CPU [index_from_runtime];
```

This is the most flexible since `index_from_runtime` can be a variable instead of just a typed out integer constant `1` or `2` etc.

Comment: this looks good if i have few macros to look up 
but in actual i have large number of registers with just that name changed which cant be added to look up table

Comment: @pavansinghal Starts to sound as if what you actually need is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76161092/584518). That's C++, but in C you can do something very similar with `#define` the base address of each hardware peripheral. And then use a macro like `UART_TX(base) = something`, which is implemented along `#define UART_TX(base) ((volatile type*)base + n)` where `n` is the register number in relation to the first hardware register of the UART peripheral.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, yes i needed a similar solution